# Get all fields with join. DJANGO

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset, django-orm

If I do

```
books = Book.objects.filter(author__name="John")
```

I get only `Book`'s fields

How can I get `Author`'s fields too, With single query?

Comment: you can use `annotate`

Answer (score 2):

Use `values` or `values_list`:

```
books_info = Book.objects.filter(author__name="John").values('book_field1', 'book_field2', 'book__author_field1','book__author_field2')
```

django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Comment: Thanks @Shang Wang. But how can I select all fields. Something like this SELECT *

Comment: Seems to be much more performant than the `select_related` I will stick with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Books.objects.select_related('author').filter(author__name="John")
```

You just need to do this.

This will get the related objects in one query.

Comment: Author related to book. Not Book related to Author. What would I do in this case?

Comment: My answer will give the Books objects which have author_name="John". Also, Author fields will be included by default. What exactly is the result you are looking for?